# How to use DynamoDB with Project Reactor?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, project-reactor

I building a Reactive JVM-based application with `Project Reactor`. During the application lifecycle, it connects to the `DynamoDB`. Which, to my knowledge, provides a non-reactive REST connection. Is there are any libraries that can handle it? Or if not, how to use DynamoDB in reactive applications?

Already tried some Spring Starters with DynamoDB, but I prefer the Standart AWS SDK wrapper - [`JCABI`](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-dynamo)

Comment: use the official AWS sdk: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-enhanced-dynamodb-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-v2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DynamoDbAsyncClient` form the [AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html) that
provides truly nonblocking asynchronous clients that implement high concurrency across a few threads.

The methods for asynchronous client return `CompletableFuture` objects but you can easily wrap them into reactive API using `Mono.fromFuture`

```
public Mono<CreateTableResponse> createTable(CreateTableRequest createTableRequest) {
    return Mono.fromFuture(dynamoDbClient.createTable(createTableRequest));
}
```