# How to test Method that call Method from a Getter?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So I'm testing some Gateways, I have this update method:

```
@Override
public Mono<Boolean> update(CustomerInfo info) {
    CustomerEntity customerEntity = new CustomerEntity();
    customerEntity.setCustomerId(info.getCustomerId());
    customerEntity.setName(info.getName());
    customerEntity.setLastName(info.getLastName());
    customerEntity.setBirthDate(info.getBirthDate());
    Expression itemExistsExpression = Expression.builder()
            .expression("attribute_exists(customerId)")
            .build();

    UpdateItemEnhancedRequest<PhysicalcardCustomerInfoEntity> updateItemEnhancedRequest = UpdateItemEnhancedRequest
            .builder(CustomerEntity.class)
            .item(customerEntity)
            .conditionExpression(itemExistsExpression)
            .ignoreNulls(true)
            .build();

    this.customerAdapter.getCustomerTable().updateItem(updateItemEnhancedRequest)
            .thenRun(() -> log.info("Updated in DynamoDB!"));

    return Mono.just(true);
}
```

I having issues trying to test this method, I think that the problem is in

```
this.customerAdapter.getCustomerTable().updateItem(updateItemEnhancedRequest).thenRun(() -> log.info("Updated in DynamoDB!"));
```

customerTable is

```
private final DynamoDbAsyncTable<V> customerTable;
```

Please someone can help?

I tried doing

```
@Test
void updateCustomerInfo() {
    Mockito.when(customerAdapter.getCustomerTable().updateItem(any(UpdateItemEnhancedRequest.class)))
            .thenReturn(Mono.empty().toFuture());

    Mono<Boolean> infoMono = customerGateway.update(dynamoData.get(0));
    StepVerifier.create(infoMono).expectComplete().verify();
}
```

but not having success.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What's the message you see, which line is affected, is there a stack trace?

Comment: returning `Mono.just(true)` is not making your code reactive. You need to build reactive flow combining different operators and return it from the method

Comment: You can wrap your completable future into `Mono` https://stackoverflow.com/a/75141531/9068895. Something like `return Mono.fromFuture(updateItem).thenReturn(true)`

Comment: what does this function `this.customerAdapter.getCustomerTable()` actually do, and why isnt it returning a `Mono/Flux`